# refresh front door locks without rekeying

Tags: doors, hardware

My front door has a "Faultless Lexington Handleset with Ball in Polished Brass" (http://www.homedepot.com/p/Faultless-Lexington-Handleset-with-Ball-in-Polished-Brass-HY7731B-F/203187008). As you can see it's all tarnished.  At Home Depot it's $60 to get a new one, but I don't want to re-key.  Is there something I can use that could bring it back to life without having to spend hours cleaning it? and  is the only way to clean it well to take if off the door?  I'm just trying to make it look good, not perfect.  Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: Buy a new one at home depot and take it to a lock shop and have them re-key it to your existing key.  Locksmiths that come to you charge much more than if walking into the shop and asking for a simple cylinder re-key.

Comment: Almost every place I've ever bought a handle\lock set will re-key it (assuming it's the same brand\compatible).

Comment: Comments above are correct, but a cheap try would be Brasso and a rag. You'd knock off the bright finish entirely and get to something matte that will tarnish more readily. Might look good; might not.

Comment: Home Depot will re-key a lock they sell for almost free.  Take your lockset in, choose a new lockset, and ask for the new to use the old key.

Comment: @wallyk only certain Home Depot's rekey cylinders in store, the stores that don't can in fact send cylinders to a store that does, but good luck finding the employee that knows it can be done.